# Getting a 500 Internal Server Error with Laravel Chat Web Application

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, chat

So I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLDjgbbBvOg&ab_channel=BBarters) tutorial on creating a chat app with Laravel and Ajax, and I followed everything letter to letter, except for the `class Chat extends \Eloquent` which I added since it works in my version of Laravel 5.1.

I will try to add everything that is in my application. I have read probably ~15 other questions and all they say is adding a verification token, and I tried, but still to no avail.

This is my console upon load of the app.
[image]

Also this is what my laravel.log console says:

```
[2016-02-25 09:12:18] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\ChatMessage' not found' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/app/Http/Controllers/ChatController.php:63
Stack trace:
#0 {main}  
[2016-02-25 09:12:18] local.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'chat.chat' doesn't exist' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:333
Stack trace:
#0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(333): PDO->prepare('select * from `...')
#1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(662): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection), 'select * from `...', Array)
#2 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(629): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#3 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(342): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#4 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1461): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('select * from `...', Array, true)
#5 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1447): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->runSelect()
#6 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(569): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->get(Array)
#7 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(303): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->getModels(Array)
#8 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(273): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->get(Array)
#9 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(154): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->first(Array)
#10 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->find(1)
#11 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(3490): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__call('find', Array)
#13 [internal function]: App\Chat->find(1)
#14 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(3504): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/app/Http/Controllers/ChatController.php(78): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__callStatic('find', Array)
#16 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/app/Http/Controllers/ChatController.php(78): App\Chat::find(1)
#17 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\ChatController->retrieveTypingStatus()
#18 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(78): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#19 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(146): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('retrieveTypingS...', Array)
#20 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\ChatController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'retrieveTypingS...')
#21 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(96): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#26 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(54): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Http\Controllers\ChatController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'retrieveTypingS...')
#27 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\\Http\\Contro...', 'retrieveTypingS...')
#28 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(140): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(724): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(726): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#35 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(699): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(675): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#42 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#43 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#45 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#48 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/public/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 {main}

Next exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'chat.chat' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `chat` where `chat`.`id` = 1 limit 1)' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
Stack trace:
#0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(629): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(342): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#2 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1461): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('select * from `...', Array, true)
#3 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1447): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->runSelect()
#4 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(569): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->get(Array)
#5 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(303): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->getModels(Array)
#6 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(273): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->get(Array)
#7 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(154): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->first(Array)
#8 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->find(1)
#9 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(3490): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__call('find', Array)
#11 [internal function]: App\Chat->find(1)
#12 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(3504): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#13 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/app/Http/Controllers/ChatController.php(78): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__callStatic('find', Array)
#14 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/app/Http/Controllers/ChatController.php(78): App\Chat::find(1)
#15 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\ChatController->retrieveTypingStatus()
#16 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(78): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(146): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('retrieveTypingS...', Array)
#18 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\ChatController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'retrieveTypingS...')
#19 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(96): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#24 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(54): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Http\Controllers\ChatController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'retrieveTypingS...')
#25 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\\Http\\Contro...', 'retrieveTypingS...')
#26 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(140): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(724): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(726): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#33 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(699): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(675): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#41 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#45 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#46 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 /Library/WebServer/Documents/chat/public/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 {main}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/{username}', function ($username) {
    return View::make('chats')->with('username', $username);
});
//ok
Route::post('sendMessage', array('uses' => 'ChatController@sendMessage'));
Route::post('isTyping', array('uses' => 'ChatController@isTyping'));
Route::post('notTyping', array('uses' => 'ChatController@notTyping'));
Route::post('retrieveChatMessages', array('uses' => 'ChatController@retrieveChatMessages'));
Route::post('retrieveTypingStatus', array('uses' => 'ChatController@retrieveTypingStatus'));
```

chats.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chats</title>
    <link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{asset('css/chats.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
        <h1 id="greeting">Hello, <span id="username">{{$username}}</span></h1>

        <div id="chat-window" class="col-lg-12">

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="typingStatus" class="col-lg-12" style="padding: 15px"></div>
            <input type="text" id="text" class="form-control col-lg-12" autofocus="" onblur="notTyping();">
            <input id="button" type="button" value="send" onclick="sendMessage();" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="{{URL::asset('js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::asset('js/chats.js')}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Chat.php Model, which I created in app/

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class Chat extends \Eloquent
{
  protected $table = 'chats';
}

?>
```

ChatMessage.php Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class ChatMessage extends \Eloquent
{
  protected $table = 'chat_messages';
}

?>
```

my ChatController.php located in app/http/controllers

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Chat;
use App\ChatMessage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class ChatController extends Controller
{
  public function sendMessage()
  {
    $username = Input::get('username');
    $text = Input::get('text');

    $chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
    $chatMessage->sender_username = $username;
    $chatMessage->message = $text;
    $chatMessage->save();

  }

  public function isTyping()
  {
    $username = Input::get('username');

    $chat = Chat::find(1);
    if($chat->user1 == $username) {
      $chat->user1_is_typing = true;
    } else {
      $chat->user2_is_typing = true;
    }

    $chat->save();

  }

  public function notTyping()
  {
    $username = Input::get('username');

    $chat = Chat::find(1);
    if($chat->user1 == $username) {
      $chat->user1_is_typing = false;
    } else {
      $chat->user2_is_typing = false;
    }

    $chat->save();

  }

  public function retrieveChatMessages()
  {
    $username = Input::get('username');

    $message = ChatMessage::where('sender_username', '!=', $username)->where('read', '=', false)->first();

    if(count($message) > 0)
    {
      $message->read = true;
      $message->save();

      return $message->message;
    }
  }

  public function retrieveTypingStatus()
  {
    $username = Input::get('username');

    $chat = Chat::find(1);

    if($chat->user1 == $username) {
      if($chat->user2_is_typing) {
        return $chat->user2;
      }
    } else {
      if($chat->user1_is_typing) {
        return $chat->user1;
      }
    }

   }


}

?>
```

my chats.js

```
var username;



$(document).ready(function()
{
    username = $('#username').html();

    pullData();



    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          sendMessage();

        }

        else
            {isTyping();}
    });
});

function pullData()
{
    retrieveChatMessages();
    retrieveTypingStatus();
    setTimeout(pullData,3000);
}

function retrieveChatMessages()
{
    $.post('http://localhost/chat/public/index.php/retrieveChatMessages', {username: username}, function(data)
    {
        if (data.length > 0)
            {$('#chat-window').append('<br><div>'+data+'</div><br>');}
    });
}

function retrieveTypingStatus()
{
    $.post('http://localhost/chat/public/index.php/retrieveTypingStatus', {username: username}, function(username)
    {
        if (username.length > 0)
            {$('#typingStatus').html(username+' is typing');}
        else
            {$('#typingStatus').html('');}
    });
}

function sendMessage()
{

    var text = $('#text').val();

    if (text.length > 0)
    {
        $.post('http://localhost/chat/public/index.php/sendMessage', {text: text, username: username}, function()
        {

            $('#chat-window').append('<br><div style="text-align: right">'+text+'</div><br>');
            $('#text').val('');
            notTyping();
        });
    }
}

function isTyping()
{
    $.post('http://localhost/chat/public/index.php/isTyping', {username: username});
}

function notTyping()
{
    $.post('http://localhost/chat/public/index.php/notTyping', {username: username});
}
```

Both my migrations: 2016_02_25_070212_create_chatmessages_table.php

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('chat_messages', function(Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->string('sender_username');
          $table->text('message');
          $table->boolean('read')->default(false);
          $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and: 2016_02_25_065913_create_chats_table.php

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('chats', function(Blueprint $table) {

          $table->increments('id');
          $table->string('user1');
          $table->string('user2');
          $table->boolean('user1_is_typing')->default(false);
          $table->boolean('user2_is_typing')->default(false);
          $table->timestamps();

        });
    }
```

Also this is my Kernel.php file, if for some reason it is needed.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,

        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```

I have absolutely no idea what to do from hereon. I have scoured google hoping to find an answer that works, so I would greatly appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Now the only thing not working is the app not knowing if the other user is typing.

Error:

[image]

This is obviously linked to my function(s) retrieveTypingStatus(), isTyping() and notTyping().

Now in my ChatController, everything using the ChatMessage Model works, but everything using the Chat Model doesn't, why is that?

Error in console:
[image]

Comment: That tut is two years old; have you tried extending Model, the class you're using, rather than the Eloquent?  Whenever I make models in L5.1/5.2, I extend Model.

Comment: Your model class name should be equal to the table name.

Comment: Actually, I just fixed it... the ChatMessage.php had `class Chat` instead of `ChatMessage`, but I'm still seeing errors, but otherwise it's works fine, why would I still be getting errors if it works?

Comment: can you show your new error logs?

Comment: @SamirChahine Please try extending Model instead of extending Eloquent.

Comment: @Daedalus I extended Model but now I get `Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null
    at CSRecorder.onQueryStateCompleted`

Comment: @SamirChahine That error appears to be caused by a chrome extension: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=114004

Comment: Should I ignore it? As it is not affecting the functionality of the app @Daedalus

Comment: @SamirChahine Unless it adversely impacts your application, yes.

Comment: There is one function that is also giving me an error, but it is not affecting the functionality of the rest of the app, could you please help me? Where do I post the code? @Daedalus

Comment: @SamirChahine You can either edit the question or ask a new question.  I'll answer in a comment, as I don't have enough energy to provide an answer right now.

Comment: @Daedalus I have updated my question, thank you.

Comment: @SamirChahine Is your Chat model still not extending Model?  And you posted the stack trace, but not the error, which is needed.

Comment: Okay i added the errors

Comment: The php error; not the js error.

Comment: Where would I find those? My app works fine even though that function doesn't so i haven't run into any "php" errors

Comment: @SamirChahine You have an image with a stack trace, but not the error that caused the stack trace.  What you posted above your second image is indeed a php error, but without the error.

Comment: I don't understand, do i copy and paste my laravel.log like i did in the question?

Comment: I don't have the energy for this right now.  Goodnight.

Comment: php is the language Laravel is based on.  If you don't know what a php error is, there's nothing I can do to help you.  Learn the basics first.

Comment: It's no problem, I fixed it, thanks for all your help